# On Amazon RDS, what consumes storage space beyond the database files?

Tags: amazon-rds, disk-space

I recently right-sized the data and log files for an RDS database, leaving just a few GB of unallocated space.  Shortly thereafter, something allocated, then deallocated, 1 GB of the margin of error.  What might have caused this?

All of the databases - including tempdb - are either tiny (MB) or at exactly the size they've been set; they add up to 197 GB, leaving 3 GB free on a 200 GB instance.  And yet:

[image: Free space dipped from 3 to 1.5 GB, then returned]

Clearly, if this happens again in a slightly greater magnitude, there will be a problem.  For now, I can simply shrink one of the database files to give a larger margin, but I'd like to understand what actually happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS support came back with a comprehensive answer.  In this case, it was transaction log backups, being written to the SQL disk before offloading to S3.  There are a few more things which can consume space, mostly temporarily.  As their tech outlined:

> As a best Practice, I would recommend to keep at around 5% free space for similar processes (Log Backups, Error Log Files, Trace Files, etc), however this may vary based on high transactional volume or bulk data upload process , which may need high disk storage temporarily.